# Unique number list

Tags: php

I have an HTML form from which a user selects numbers using checkboxes. The numbers are put into an PHP array like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="formnumber[]" value="1" />
```

There are 24 numbers to pick from 1 to 24. I want to output a list of 10 unique lines with 5 unique numbers per line using the numbers from the array.

e.g.: I pick 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 from the form. The output would look like this:

```
2 16 4 1 15
10 13 2 4 5
12 1 3 16 11

etc etc (10 lines)
```

---

I got it to work like this but i still get a duplicate every now and then. I can enter 5 to 24 numbers in the form and get mostly unique random lines of 4 numbers in the output.

```
$i=1;

while ($i<=$xresults) {

$numbers = $_POST['formnumber'];

shuffle($numbers);

$counter = 0; 

    foreach ($numbers as $number1) {

        echo "<span>$number1</span> ";

    if(++$counter >= 4) { break; }

}

$i++;

echo '<p>';

 }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what's not worked? There are a lot of ways to write the whole thing for you, and that's not really what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: It's not clear how you've selected which numbers output to which lines.

Answer (score 4):

So basically you want it to pick different combinations of 5 of the selected boxes.

Well, I would do something like this:

```
$flip = array_flip($_POST['formnumber']);
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    $combo = array_rand($flip,5);
    echo implode(" ",$combo)."\n";
}
```

Comment: what is the advantage of using `array_rand` vs `shuffle`? I wonder why you picked one over the other...

Comment: Thank you so much that is exactly what i needed. I was working on code but just couldn't get my head around it.

Comment: @Floris `array_rand` selects random keys from the array. `shuffle` scrambles the original array.